# Changing text with a click event: how to restore default state of text in jQuery if/else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a click event that calls a function which makes some CSS changes (acts on Text in 3 unique text elements).

The function (below) works, but is lacking a 'restore default' function (to return the text to its original state), AND is in dire need of refactoring.

Q: How can the original state of ALL text elements be restored once user clicks away from this section?

Here is the partially working, ugly function:

```
function txtResize() {

        var clicked = this.id;

        if (clicked == "Text1")
        {
            $("#" + clicked).css("opacity", "1");
            $("#Text2, #Text3").css("opacity", "0.2");
        }
        else if (clicked == "Text2") 
        {
            $("#" + clicked).css("opacity", "1");
            $("#Text1, #Text3").css("opacity", "0.2");
        }
        else if (clicked == "Text3")
        {
            $("#" + clicked).css("opacity", "1");
            $("#Text1, #Text2").css("opacity", "0.2");
        }
         // code above is ok, below does not work

        else if ( !(clicked == "Text1") && !(clicked == "Text2") && !(clicked == "Text3") ) 
        {
            $("#Text1, #Text2, #Text3").css("opacity", "1");  // return to default state
        }   

 };
```

UPDATE: (20 Jan) - Have improved the code, but it still somewhat clunky and involves two distinct functions.

```
function txtResize() {

        var clicked = this.id;

        if (clicked === "Text1" || clicked === "Text2" || clicked === "Text3" ) 
        {
            $("#Text1, #Text2, #Text3").animate({"opacity": "0.2"}, 500)
            $("#" + clicked).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 200);
        }
};

function txtRestore(){
        $("#Text1, #Text2, #Text3").animate({"opacity": "1"}, 1000);
};
```

Comment: Perhaps the note on refactoring could be de-emphasized but the main issue is that my text does not return to its original state (two of the paragraphs remain opacity = unreadable.  I want the last statement in if/else to restore text back, and figured in doing so many would point out how badly the code needs refactoring so I threw that in as well.  Will edit to ensure focus is on restoring the default value of text, not refactoring.

Answer (score 3):

as a first step I would rewrite the last if statement

```
else if ((clicked =! "Text1") && (clicked != "Text2") && (clicked != "Text3") ) 
    {
        $("#ActText, #AdaptText, #PlanText").css("opacity", "1");  // return to default state
    }
```

After that you could rewrite it as a switch statement: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

edit : this would be better...

```
var textArray = new Array("Text1","Text2","Text3");
if($.inArray(clicked,textArray){
    $("#Text2, #Text3").css("opacity", "1");
}
else {
 $("#" + clicked).css("opacity", "0.2");
}
```

Comment: Your solution itself needs refactoring, I would use an array and `$.inArray()`.

Comment: Thanks Blacksheep, I didn't even notice that each action in the if statements was the same.

Comment: The text with opacity = 1 should stand alone, the other two text elements should take opacity 0.2.  I think this solution has it backwards, meaning if text2 or text3 is clicked, then what?  IOW, shouldn't #text2 and #text3 also be variables?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative. I do use that technic a lot as it shrinks the amount of code.

The `exec` function is self invoked and returns a new function (this is `closure`); so the elements you want to work with are accessible in the inner function.

```
var exec = (function() {
    var $el = $('#Text1, #Text2, #Text3'); //allows you to use easily .siblings later    
    return function(id) { //closure
        $el.filter(function() { return this.id === id; }).css("opacity", "1");
        $el.siblings().css("opacity", "0.2");
    };
})(); //self invoked: it returns a new function but has access to $el

var rollback = function() {
    $("#ActText, #AdaptText, #PlanText").css("opacity", "1");  // return to default state
};

['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3'].indexOf(this.id) > -1 ? exec(this.id) : rollback(); //indexOf is part oc ECMAscript 5th version. So ensure you can use it or provide an alternative/shim
```

It is not bullet-proof as I didn't test it. But it provides you with a get-go :)